# How to run npm command as apache user

Tags: linux, apache, npm, server

Help : How to run npm commands as apache user ?

`sudo -u apache npm run prod` it says "npm command" is not found.

Although other user can use npm except for apache user.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the default path for user apache does not include the directory where npm is installed. You could try specifying the full path, something like `sudo -u apache /full/path/to/npm run prod`, but if the default path isn't set as needed you may run into other problems. You can invoke sudo with `-E` to preserve the current environment: if that works you might be able to replace `-E` with `--preserve-env=PATH`, assuming that only the PATH variable is needed.

Depending on what you're trying to do, it might be better to install npm where apache can find it, or change the user profile for apache to include the current location of npm. Running apache with an uncontrolled environment could lead to security problems.